# It's possible copy many PostgreSQL tables into one file?

Tags: postgresql, csv, postgresql-copy

Is there possibility to copy (In loop) many tables into one csv file?

Command copy overwrite file so I get only last set of data... in file:

```
execute 'COPY (select * from '||source_table_name||' order by time) to ''F:/csv/rap/'||source_file_name||'.csv'' with DELIMITER '';'' CSV HEADER';
```

I know that could write it into one table and copy to csv but it would be over 68 000 tables to copy to almost 2 000 files so I would like avoid that.

Comment: Copy to stdout && redirect to a file. Or copy to separate files and concatenate. But the **real** problem is: 68K tables. Why?

Comment: So there are identical tables with fixed columns (collected in monthly tables).  I need to pass the data for processing and it will be more convenient to have it in one file than several for the same object.

Comment: The file system is your friend.

Comment: telemetry data - the system is organized like this, I know it makes it difficult to operate on data, but the speed of reading by web applications is brilliant

Comment: Ok. powershell and the merging of files. Thanks.

Comment: If the tables have the same schema and you want to make the merge in the database then I think you ought to investigate the `union` operator in Postgres.

Comment: Couldn't you create a view that selects all the tables with a `UNION ALL`, and then COPY SELECT that view to a file? If that doesn't work, there a workaround over here, but it is a bit of a hack https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/149774